# Building LINQ Expressions Dynamically w/ Unknown Types

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I am wondering if it is possible to use this expression builder class to generate lambda expressions dynamically where the type to be filtered is not known at compile time.

I have a method that constructs the expression,

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T>(IList<QueryFilter> filters)
```

And a QueryFilter object,

```
public class QueryFilter 
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }       
    public ExpressionType OpType { get; set; } 
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Where you can generate a new expression that filters object T using the QueryFilters that are passed in. I want to develop a method where the type isn't known, ie.

```
public static Expression<Func<T,bool>> GetExpression(IList<QueryFilter> filters, Type type)
```

So I can pass the type as a parameter, from calls to System.Reflection, instead of having to specify it in code. For example something along these lines,

```
    public static Expression NewExpression(IList<QueryFilter> filters, Type T)
    {
        return GetExpression<Type>(filters); 
    }
```

If its possible to use this syntax where Type replaces the generic 'T'? Since I do not think I can specify a runtime dynamic Type within the < > brackets, is there another way, perhaps using

```
Func<object,bool>
```

instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try working with  DynamicExpression.ParseLambda

Comment: This should work, thanks. However one problem I noticed is that when you specify the string representation of a Binary lambda expression for instance, "TimeOfAction > @0", the .ToString() representation of the built expression says 'GreaterThan' or 'LessThan' instead of the appropriate symbol. So how can I dynamically set the binary operation?

Comment: Sorry I don't know, maybe you should ask another question

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) or the [Dynamic Linq Library (.NET 3.5).](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Comment: I noticed that the Dynamic Linq library and Linq.Expressions namespace both have a DynamicExpression class with different members, so the IDE throws a complaint about the conflict. How do you typically resolve that?

Comment: @sean: Looking at the MSDN documentation, it appears that the `DynamicExpression` class was incorporated into .NET Framework 4.0, with some "enhancements." Therefore, the Dynamic Linq library would only work unmodified under .NET 3.5